# MySQL database suddenly missing, went back to default with no errors or warnings

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp, mamp-pro

Am new to WordPress, used MAMP-PRO for windows to setup the Apache, MySQL, PHP and it worked fine.  Got a theme and built a website.  Was testing why the MAMP Pro would not serve the web pages.

When another PC connected to my IP, it would serve only the text but no images and no javascript files.

Then MAMP Pro would put a message saying Trial version expired.  I closed this out and am running just MAMP.  But somewhere along the way? my website is gone, the MySQL database is not there, at all.  In the PHPadmin page, it looks like a brand new installation before anything, before wordpress was added.

At the top of the admin page it says 'RECENT', click on that and my database name is listed, click and it gets an error #1046 No Database Selected

In switching between MAMP Pro and regular MAMP would the path to the database be changed?  How can the database be found?

Comment: Added another database with same name as before to this MAMP database, then it placed a new folder where I expected it in the mysql area.  Looks like the original folder with db's just got zapped.  Not even in recycle bin.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what MAMP PRo versus MAMP does; it's very possible they use different paths for the MySQL data directory (datadir). If they do, you should be able to copy the files from the pro datadir to the non-pro version and use them (I'd make a backup of the non-pro directory then completely replace it, rather than trying to merge the two directories which can cause permissions issues and other problems).

However, if the missing databases are only missing when you connect from the other machine, it's more likely to be a MySQL permissions problem. It's possible that you're connecting from the remote machine as the anonymous user which might not have permissions to access any of your existing databases. You can try connecting from the local machine as root to test this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Got a response, other docs said the db 'ALWAYS' lives at MAMP\db, but it's in another area:

---

Yes, if you were working with the two week trial , and you want to go back to the free version you need to do the following.

Move your database files from

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Appsolute\MAMPPRO\db\

to

C:\MAMP\db\

Then you can run MAMP Free with your old site.

---

But doing this was not the fix, MySQL would not start.  I copied the original my.ini file from the mampPRO path into the MAMP\conf\mysql\my.ini file

Now restart the MAMP server and most of the page is there.  One of the main images, also the logo are just not there, but at least the majority of the website is there.  Trying to edit these areas, the logo and main slider image will not display.  Upload the image or pick another image, they do not get displayed.